# Switch executes normally and then throws an error

Tags: node.js, discord.js, switch-statement

That's kinda weird one.
I wrote code checking if discord message content (**msg.content**) starts with prefix (e.g. "**!add-badword foo**") and returning string without prefix. Then switch is supposed to compare this with avaliable commands and execute some code. Thing is, all of this works normally, it executes code as it should, and then, after complete execution of switch, it throws error.

What should I do to fix it?

Function returning string without prefix:

```
async function isCommand (msg){
    let q = await serverConfig.findOne({_id: msg.guildId+""},{prefix:1})
    if(msg.content.indexOf(q.prefix)==0){
        return msg.content.slice(1)
    }else{
        return false
    }
}
```

Problematic switch:

```
const command = await isCommand(msg);
switch(command.split(' ')[0]){
    default: 
        msg.reply('Command not recognized');
        break;
    case 'set-prefix':
        msg.reply('Prefix changed to ' + command.split(' ')[1]);
        break;
    case 'ignore-channel':
        msg.reply('Ignoring channel ' + command.split(' ')[1]);
        break;
    case 'unignore-channel':
        msg.reply('Channel ' + command.split(' ')[1] + ' unignored');
        break;
    case 'ignore-badword':
        msg.reply('Ignoring word ' + command.split(' ')[1]);
        break;
    case 'unignore-badword':
        msg.reply('Word ' + command.split(' ')[1] + ' unignored');
        break;
    case 'add-badword':
        msg.reply('Added word ' + command.split(' ')[1] + ' to bad words');
        break;
    case 'remove-badword':
        msg.reply('Removed word ' + command.split(' ')[1] + ' from bad words');
        break;    
}
```

(Not?) working code effect on Discord:
[image: (not?) working code effect]

Error:

```
node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: command.split is not a function
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\GitHub\forgotten-droid\index.js:56:29)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
Emitted 'error' event on Client instance at:
    at emitUnhandledRejectionOrErr (node:events:394:10)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:85:21)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I found the solution. Code was trigerred by bot's message too, and because it did not included prefix, **command** variable was set to **false**. Because of that, switch failed, because **false** has no  **split()** function. So I nested my problematic switch like this:

```
if (command) {
    //switch here
}
```